# Finding the X,Y,Z cartesion position of 3 intersecting sphere

Tags: c#, collision

I'm trying to work out the 3D point in which 3 spheres will collide. At the moment, from a top down perspective, I have X, Z position of where these spheres meet. When they do, I place a game object to show where it is they have met.

This is the code:

```
public void calculatePoints_H(Vector3 c1p, Vector3 c2p, float c1r, float c2r, out Vector3 startLine, out Vector3 endLine)
{

    //get the positions
    Vector3 P0 = c1p;
    Vector3 P1 = c2p;

    float d,a,h;

    //d is the distance between centres
    d = Vector3.Distance(P0,P1);
    //a is checking if the spheres are inside, outside or colliding
    a = (c1r*c1r - c2r*c2r + d*d)/(2*d);
    //
    h = Mathf.Sqrt(c1r*c1r - a*a);

    //Debug.Log(d + " " + a + " " + h);

    Vector3 P2 = (P1 - P0);
            P2 = (P2 * (a/d));
            P2 = (P2 + P0);

    //Debug.Log(P2);

    float x3,y3,x4,y4 = 0;

    x3 = P2.x + h*(P1.y - P0.y)/d;
    y3 = P2.y - h*(P1.x - P0.x)/d;

    x4 = P2.x - h*(P1.y - P0.y)/d;
    y4 = P2.y + h*(P1.x - P0.x)/d;;

    //Debug.Log(x3 + " " + y3 + " " + x4 + " " + y4);

    Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(x3,0,y3), new Vector3(x4,0,y4),Color.green);

    startLine = new Vector3(x3,0,y3);

    endLine = new Vector3(x4,0,y4);


}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is find the height at which point these 3 meet. The reason for this is because at the moment, my 3 spheres need to all be on the same plane. When really, I want the flexibility to have them placed anywhere I wish.

Could someone please help me amend my code so that I can incorporate height into the equation as well, or point me in the right direction of what I need to do?

Comment: Why don't you use an OctTree to simplify this process?

Comment: I've never used one before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the fact, that "collision" (I assume you define it as "points touched by all 3 spheres at once") of randomly placed three spheres produces `0, 1, 2` or `Inf` number of points of collision, strictly depending on the position and radius of each sphere?

It's not just one point.

You need to simulate the space and scan it for interesting points (ie by the suggested OctTree), or you need to actually solve the three equations:

```
(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2=r0^2
(x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2=r1^2
(x-x2)^2+(y-y2)^2=r2^2
```

where xNyNrN are the sphere's params and xy are the 'collision point' coords.

You can either do it algebraically (see wolfram aplha if you dont like maths), or you can try any zero-finder on:

```
(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2 + (x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2 + (x-x2)^2+(y-y2)^2 - r0^2 - r1^2 - r2^2
```

I have not tried nor analyzed it, but spheres are totally smooth and totally convex, so there shouldn't be any malicious local minimums and even simple bisection or gradient sliding could happen to be enough.

However, note that while "solve it algebraically" can easily show you that there are 2 or INF points of collision, the "scanning the space" or zero-finder might return you just one point, the first/best it has hit (or none). In such case, to get the other minimums, you may have to start it with a bit different 'starting position'.. but that depends on the exact scanning algorithm you choose.

EDIT: of course the equations above should be 3D, so add `(z-z0)^2` thrice, sorry. I'm not correcting that as it'd make everything less readable.